# Node.js - render after receiving Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have the following code:

```
app.use(_.get('*', function *() {
    const store = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore)(combineReducers(reducers));
    const props = yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => match({routes, location: this.req.url}, (err, redirect, props) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(`Router error ${err}`);
            reject(this.throw(500));
        } else if (redirect) {
            this.redirect(redirect);
        } else if (props) {
            resolve(props);
        } else {
            reject(this.throw(404));
        }
    }));
    try {
        yield trigger('fetch', props.components, {
            dispatch: store.dispatch,
            ...props
        });
    }catch(e) {
        return;
    }

    const isAmp = this.req.url.match('amp=1');
    rp(reqUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
        let repy = JSON.parse(response)
        isOnline = repy.type
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error when request')
      });
if (isAmp){
    yield this.render('amp', {
        body: renderToString(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RouterContext {...props}/>
            </Provider>
        )
    });
}  else  {
    yield this.render('turbo.xml', {
        body: renderToString(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RouterContext {...props}/>
            </Provider>
        )
    });
}}
));
```

Tell me, please, how can I render only after receiving a promise from this part of the code

```
.then(function (response) {
        let repy = JSON.parse(response)
        if (repy.type === "online'){
         render
         }
    })
```

I tried to paste the check in `if`, but the function does not wait for the promise. I read several posts about promises, but understanding did not come to me...

I will be very grateful for any of your advice.

Comment: You just need to pass whole `if` inside `then`

Comment: What version of `Node.js` are you using?

Comment: You are using a very weird library/framework that is important to your problem that you are not tagging here. I have no idea how to fix this because in regular Express.js there is no issue to render after a promise because express callbacks aren't generators. What is `_`? underscore.js or some other library/framework?

Comment: @TienDuong so i have an error:  `yield is a reserved word`

Comment: @goto1 `Node.js 4.2.4`

Comment: @slebetman `_` is `koa-route`

Comment: You're getting syntax error on `yield`? Wow, your using node version 0. That's really old and was the beta version. Update to at least node 4 (the first release version of node). I strongly suggest you use node 10 at minimum or it will be very hard to use solutions on stackoverflow (arrow functions, Promises etc.)

Comment: @slebetman I updated to `Node.js 10.2.1` as you said, but still get this error `yield is reserved word` when i  pass whole `if` inside `then`

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya it looks like your mixing your `Express` code with `React` code? And why are you using `koa-route` if you're using `Express`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use async await for that.

It works like this

You put the word async before your function

```
async function() {
    let response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(error) return Promise.reject(...)
        return Promise.resolve(...)
    } ) 

     //here response will be equal to whatever is returned from the promise 


}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not sure if a function can be both async and a generator (`function*`) - I don't believe `async function*` is valid syntax

Comment: Why do you need a generator function?

Comment: I don't need a generator function but the OP is using a generator function. You are not reading the question carefully enough

Comment: And the OP is mixing generators and promises `yield new Promise...` - I have no idea how that would work

Comment: I now think the OP is using an old library/framework to emulate async/await using generators via a design pattern called trampolines. There are several trampoline libraries on npm. Trampolines allow you to use the `yield` keyword to emulate `await`. People used to do this before `async/await` was even suggested but it wasn't a very popular approach because a lot of people simply ignored generators

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish with the generator function so I maybe wrong but I think you could change the generator function and yield into an async await function to ge the desired behaviour

Comment: Looks like OP is using `Node.js 4`, so `async/await` is not going to work in this case